# Wrong Image number in shadowbox when using jCarouselLite

Tags: jquery, shadowbox, jcarousellite

I have a gallery in my page with many images. I am using jCarouselLite for showing all these images. When I click one of these images I want to show them with the Shadowbox. It works fine. The problem is that due to jCarouselLite the amount of images shown at the bottom of shadowbox has been tripled. So instead of "1 οf 4" I see "1 of 12".
Is there a way to correct this number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using on i.e jsfiddle.net or beskope url?

Comment: I just call the  Shadowbox.init(); and the  $(".carousel").jCarouselLite(); And the html is <a href="myImage.png"  rel='shadowbox[images];player=img'>

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has nothing to do with jCarouselLite and more to do with your "rel" element matching through all 12 images. The Shadowbox is grouping all 12 images. Please provide the full code or a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is cloned element, try to initiate shadowBox before jCarouselLite, if that won't help, change jCarousel plugin where elements are grouped ( i guess there should be something like `$('[rel=' + variable + ']')` to `$(':not(.cloned) [rel=' + variable + ']')` ) It's just first thought.